# Oracle Database: Can I do data pump exp (not expdp) from 11g source db to do imp (not impdp) into the target db which is 10g?

Tags: oracle

Can I do data pump exp (not expdp) from 11g db (source) then imp (not impdp) into the 10g db (target)? Is tha possible?

And how about from 10g db (source) to do exp and imp to 11g db(target)?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "data pump exp (not expdp)"... the Data Pump export is expdp. Do you mean the old "exp" ?

Comment: And why wouldn't you use Data Pump instead of the old tools?

Comment: Since my co-workers said, using exp/imp is better than expdp/impdb for smaller import jobs..

Comment: It's true that for small tables exp/imp will whip expdp/impdp any day.  We are talking <1000 rows since there is a lot of overhead as it ramps up the datapump processes. I exported 15 small tables using the old tool in time it took for dp to complete 1 table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_datpmp.htm) you can specify that the job doing the export produce values in a given version. That is to say, you can tell the job doing the export to produce 10g output so that it can be accepted by the destination database. There are, of course, some caveats which must not be ignored. Specifically, check out the parameters for the `OPEN` function on `DBMS_DATAPUMP`.

Comment: We don't do the network export-import, but we do files with specific version numbers. So, the answer is no, but something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a 10g exp to do the export from 11g and the 10g imp to import into 10g.

A 10g imp will refuse to work with an 11g exp